# F# -> Implement IComparable for HashSet<'a>

Tags: f#

Is it possible to somehow implement `IComparable` for a `HashSet<'a>`? The reason for this is that I have following record declared:

```
[<StructuralComparison>]
type Category = { 
    mutable Id: string; 
    Name: string; 
    SavePath: string;
    Tags: HashSet<Tag> }

and Tag = { Tag:string; }
```

As you can see, then Tags in the `Category` record is of type `HashSet<Tag>` - and in order to map a sequence of Categories to a Map, I'll need to implement the `IComparable` somehow... else it will just result in:

> The struct, record or union type
>   'Category' has the
>   'StructuralComparison' attribute but
>   the component type 'HashSet' does
>   not satisfy the 'comparison'

Please note that I cant use anything else than a `HashSet<'a>` since the database I'm working with dosent understand any fsharp-ish lists at all.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'll assume you want to compare and equate `Category`s by taking only `Id`, `Name`, and `SavePath` into account (in that order), making the record behave as though `Tags` wasn't present:

```
open System
open System.Collections.Generic

[<CustomComparison; CustomEquality>]
type Category =
    { mutable Id : string;
      Name       : string;
      SavePath   : string;
      Tags       : HashSet<Tag> }
    member private this.Ident = this.Id, this.Name, this.SavePath
    interface IComparable<Category> with
        member this.CompareTo other =
            compare this.Ident other.Ident
    interface IComparable with
        member this.CompareTo obj =
            match obj with
              | null                 -> 1
              | :? Category as other -> (this :> IComparable<_>).CompareTo other
              | _                    -> invalidArg "obj" "not a Category"
    interface IEquatable<Category> with
        member this.Equals other =
            this.Ident = other.Ident
    override this.Equals obj =
        match obj with
          | :? Category as other -> (this :> IEquatable<_>).Equals other
          | _                    -> false
    override this.GetHashCode () =
        hash this.Ident

and Tag = { Tag : string; }
```

However, if instead you want to compare by `Name` and equate by `Id` then consider the following:

```
open System
open System.Collections.Generic

[<CustomComparison; CustomEquality>]
type Category =
    { mutable Id : string;
      Name       : string;
      SavePath   : string;
      Tags       : HashSet<Tag> }
    interface IComparable<Category> with
        member this.CompareTo { Name = name } =
            this.Name.CompareTo name
    interface IComparable with
        member this.CompareTo obj =
            match obj with
              | null                 -> 1
              | :? Category as other -> (this :> IComparable<_>).CompareTo other
              | _                    -> invalidArg "obj" "not a Category"
    interface IEquatable<Category> with
        member this.Equals { Id = id } =
            this.Id = id
    override this.Equals obj =
        match obj with
          | :? Category as other -> (this :> IEquatable<_>).Equals other
          | _                    -> false
    override this.GetHashCode () =
        this.Id.GetHashCode ()

and Tag = { Tag : string; }
```

Answer (score 3):

See

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/archive/blogs/dsyme/equality-and-comparison-constraints-in-f

Briefly, I think you want to apply the `CustomEquality` and `CustomComparison` attributes to this type and then implement it yourself.