# Built-in "< > compare" doesn't work with "IComparable<T>"?

Tags: f#, comparison

I have a Discriminated Union, and I hope to use built in operators like `> < compare max` for it.

```
[<CustomComparison>]
type SymbolType = 
    | A
    | B
    | C
    | D

    interface IComparable<SymbolType> with
        member x.CompareTo y =
            match x, y with
            | A, A-> 0
            | A, _ -> 1
            | _, A-> -1
            | _, _ -> 0
```

I understand I can use `IComparable`, but then i have to do a `null` check, what's worse is that I have to cast it like `(SymbolType) y` which I assume would be time consuming.

Comment: possible duplicate of [F# -> Implement IComparable for HashSet<'a>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5557899/f-implement-icomparable-for-hashseta)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just implement the required methods with thin wrappers:

```
[<CustomComparison>] 
[<CustomEquality>] 
type SymbolType = 
    | A
    | B
    | C
    | D
    override x.Equals y =
       match y with
       | :? SymbolType as t -> (((x :> IComparable<_>).CompareTo) t)=0
       | _ -> false
    interface IComparable with
        member x.CompareTo y =
            match y with
            | :? SymbolType as t -> ((x :> IComparable<_>).CompareTo) t
            | _ -> failwith "bad comparison"
    interface IComparable<SymbolType> with
        member x.CompareTo y =
            match x, y with
            | A, A-> 0
            | A, _ -> 1
            | _, A-> -1
            | _, _ -> 0
```

This way does avoid any duplicate typing.

Comment: After ur code, why cannot I then use `A.CompareTo B`? it says `CompareTo` is not defined?

Comment: @colinfang You'd have to write `(A :> IComparable).CompareTo(B)` because the interface is implemented implicitly (the methods are hidden).

Comment: @TomasPetricek: Do you mean _explicitly_?

Comment: @Daniel Yes, exactly :-), the interface is implemented _explicitly_!

Answer (score 3):

You can *already* use standard comparison operators on the type. The built-in implementation uses the order of declarations of the individual cases, so:

```
type SymbolType =  A | B | C | D 

// Behavior of built-in comparison
A < B   = true
D <= C  = false
max B D = D
```

This looks very fragile, so maybe it is not the best thing to rely on. If you have cases that do not contain other values, you can use *enum* instead of *discriminated union* and define the ordering you wish:

```
type SymbolType =  
  | A = 1
  | B = 2
  | C = 4
  | D = 3

// The order is now defined by your code
SymbolType.C < SymbolType.D = false
```

Answer (score 0):

On CLR, operators are static functions, so you can't define them in an interface. But boxing can also be avoided if your use the interface as a constraint of type parameter of a generic function.

```
int Compare<T>(T lhs, T rhs) where T : IComparable<T>
{
  return lhs.CompareTo(rhs) // no boxing
}
```

Sorry, I'm not familiar with F#, so I wrote the example in C#.

Comment: The equivalent to this in F# is `let inline compare (a:'t :> IComparable<'t>) (b:'t) = a.CompareTo(b)`