# Subtracting Records from a Set using case-insensitive comparison

Tags: f#, record, string-comparison

I have a set of records:

```fsharp
type Person =
    {
        Name : string
        Age : int
    }


let oldPeople =
    set [ { Name = "The Doctor"; Age = 1500 };
          { Name = "Yoda";       Age = 900 } ]
```

Unlike the hardcoded example above, the set of data actually comes from a data source (over which I have very little control). Now I need to subtract a set of data from another data source. In general, the data in this second source matches, but occasionally there is a difference in captialization:

```fsharp
let peopleWhoAreConfusedAboutTheirAge =
    set [ { Name = "THE DOCTOR"; Age = 1500 } ]
```

When I attempt to subtract the second set from the first, it fails because the string comparison is case sensitive:

```fsharp
let peopleWhoKnowHowOldTheyAre =
    oldPeople - peopleWhoAreConfusedAboutTheirAge
```

```
val peopleWhoKnowHowOldTheyAre : Set<Person> =
  set [{Name = "The Doctor";
        Age = 1500;}; {Name = "Yoda";
                       Age = 900;}]
```

Is there a way to perform a case-insensitive comparison for the `Name` field of the `People` record?

Answer (score 2):

This is what I've implemented so far, though there may be a better way to do it.

My solution was to override the `Equals` function on the `People` record so as to perform a case-insensitive comparison. Set subtraction uses the `Equals` function to determine if two records match one another. By overriding `Equals`, I was forced (via warning and error) to override `GetHashCode` and implement `IComparable` (as well as set the `CustomEquality` and `CustomComparison` attributes):

```fsharp
[<CustomEquality; CustomComparison>]
type Person =
    {
        Name : string
        Age : int
    }

    member private this._internalId =
        this.Name.ToLower() + this.Age.ToString()

    interface System.IComparable with
        member this.CompareTo obj =
            let other : Person = downcast obj
            this._internalId.CompareTo( other._internalId )

    override this.Equals( other ) =
        match other with
        | :? Person as other -> 
            System.String.Compare( this._internalId, other._internalId ) = 0
        | _ -> false

    override this.GetHashCode() =
        this._internalId.GetHashCode()
```

This, however, seems to do the trick:

```fsharp
let oldPeople =
    set [ { Name = "The Doctor"; Age = 1500 };
          { Name = "Yoda";       Age = 900 } ]

let peopleWhoAreConfusedAboutTheirAge =
    set [ { Name = "THE DOCTOR"; Age = 1500 } ]

let peopleWhoKnowHowOldTheyAre =
    oldPeople - peopleWhoAreConfusedAboutTheirAge
```

```
val peopleWhoKnowHowOldTheyAre : Set<Person> = set [{Name = "Yoda";
                                                     Age = 900;}]
```

If you know a better solution (involving less code), please post it rather than comment on this answer. I will happily accept a less verbose, awkward solution.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another approach:

```
type Name(value) =
  member val Value = value
  override this.Equals(that) =
    match that with 
    | :? Name as name -> StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase.Equals(this.Value, name.Value)
    | _ -> false
  override this.GetHashCode() =
    StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase.GetHashCode(this.Value)

type Person =
  {
    Name: Name
    Age: int
  }

{Name=Name("John"); Age=21} = {Name=Name("john"); Age=21} //true
```

Comment: Just add the `IComparable` implementation and it's what the OP wants.

Comment: I had considered this approach, but it does seem to make the code where I use the Person Record a bit more verbose. I like to contain verbosity when possible.

Comment: If you don't want to forego the structural equality/structural comparison which F# records provide by default, you need to wrap either the field or the whole record in a class, or union, on which to enact custom equality/custom comparison. See e.g. [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12744831/built-in-compare-doesnt-work-with-icomparablet/12745018#12745018)

Comment: if copying the above, consider that OrdinalIgnoreCase and/or some other culture invariant comparison is normally what you want, not CurrentCulture-based